# Majority element in an array.It

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int maj, count, n = 6;
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4};

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        maj = arr[i];
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 9; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == maj) count++;
        }
        if (count > n / 2) {
            break; /* I think some problem is here ,if majority element not found then it takes last element as the majority element */
        }
    }
    printf("%d", maj);
}
```

It is giving correct output if majority ellement is there but incorrect output if no majority element is there for example if array is {1,2,3,4} it is giving output as 4. please help!!

Comment: You know that you hard coded `n = 6` ?

Comment: What *should* it do when there's no majority element, assuming it's written the way you want? You've included no logic to handle that case.

Comment: Correct version of your code will have complexity  - `O(n^2)`. Check for more [efficient solution](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/majority-element/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int maj, count, n = 7; //n is size of arr
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4};
    int isFound = 0; //0 -> false, 1 -> true

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        maj = arr[i];
        count = 1;  //first elements is itself
        isFound = 0;  //by default we assume that no major elements is found

        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) { //iterate from next elements onwards to right in array
            if (arr[j] == maj) count++;
        }
        if (count > n / 2) {
            isFound = 1;
            break; //major elements found; no need to iterator further; just break the loop now
        }
    }
    if(isFound)   printf("%d ", maj);
    else printf("no major element");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to use `isFound`, we can check the same through `i>=n`. `if(i>=n)` then no majority element else there is a majority element.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS yes, thats another way :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Try not to use magic numbers. Usually as in your program they are a reason for program bugs. For example you declared the array `arr` as having 7 elements however the variable `n` that should keep the number of elements in the array is initialized with the value `6`. Another magic number `9` is used in the loop

```
for (int j = 9; j < n; j++) {
            ^^^
```

There is no need to write the outer loop that travers the whole array. Also the program does not report the case when the majority number does not exist in the array.

Using your approach with two loops the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( ; i < ( N + 1 ) / 2; i++ )
    {
        size_t count = 1;
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; count < N / 2 + 1 && j < N; j++ )
        {
            if ( a[i] == a[j] ) ++count;
        }

        if ( !( count < N / 2 + 1) ) break;
    }

    if ( i != ( N + 1 ) / 2 )
    {
        printf( "The majority is %d\n", a[i] );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "There is no majority element" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
The majority is 2
```